# Usage of ReentrantReadWriteLock in javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ImageCache

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

When reading JDK codes, I tried to find some usage of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, and found that the only usage is in `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ImageCache`.

I have two questions with the usage of `ReentrantReadWriteLock` here:

I can understand the `readLock` used in the `getImage` method, and the `writeLock` used in the `setImage` method, but why is a `readLock` used in the `flush` method? Isn't the `flush` method also some kind of "write", since it changes the map:

```
public void flush() {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
        map.clear();
    } finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

The other question: why not use a `ConcurrentHashMap` here, since it will provide some concurrent writes to different `mapEntries` and provide more concurrency than `ReadWriteLock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Second Question First:

> `ReentrantReadWriteLocks` can be used to improve concurrency in some uses of some kinds of Collections. This is typically worthwhile only when the collections are expected to be large, accessed by more reader threads than writer threads, and entail operations with overhead that outweighs synchronization overhead. - from [ReentrantReadWriteLock Documentation](http://download.codetrails.com/livedoc/published/0.7.0/jre/jre/1.7.0/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)

All of the points mentioned above correspond to an image cache. As for *"why not use a `ConcurrentHashMap`?"* - `ImageCache` uses a `LinkedHashMap` which has no concurrent implementation. For speculation as to why, refer to this SO question: [Why there is no ConcurrentLinkedHashMap class in jdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300115/why-there-is-no-concurrentlinkedhashmap-class-in-jdk)

#### First Question:

I too question why the `flush` method doesn't use the `writeLock` like the `setImage` method. After all it is structurally modifying the map.

After reviewing the [`javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ImageCache`](http://j6a.ru/com_2sun_2java_2swing_2plaf_2nimbus_2_image_cache_8java_source.html) and [`PixelCountSoftReference`](http://j6a.ru/com_2sun_2java_2swing_2plaf_2nimbus_2_image_cache_8java_source.html#l00173) sources along with the [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://download.codetrails.com/livedoc/published/0.7.0/jre/jre/1.7.0/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) and [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) documentations, I'm left without a definitive answer.
Although I'm further confused by `flush` using a `readLock`, since `ReentrantReadWriteLock's` documentation has the following example, where a `writeLock` is used when clearing a `TreeMap`.

```
// For example, here is a class using a TreeMap that is expected to be 
// large and concurrently accessed.
class RWDictionary {
    private final Map<String, Data> m = new TreeMap<String, Data>();
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock w = rwl.writeLock();

    // other code left out for brevity

    public void clear() {
        w.lock();  // write lock
        try { m.clear(); } // clear the TreeMap
        finally { w.unlock(); }
    }
}
```

The only thing I can do is speculate.

**Speculation:**

- Maybe the author(s) made a mistake, highly unlikely but not impossible.
- It's intentional. I have some ideas as to why it may be intentional, but I'm not sure how to word them and they're probably wrong.
- The author(s) were the only ones using the `ImageCache` code and knew when and how (not) to use the `flush` method. This is unlikely as well.

It would be interesting to ask the author(s) why they used a `readLock` instead of a `writeLock`, via email, but no authors or emails are listed in the source. Perhaps sending an email to Oracle would result in an answer, I'm not to sure how to go about that.

Hopefully someone will come along and provide an actual answer. Good question.