How to resolve ConcurrentModificationException on shrink for LRUCache which uses LinkedHashMap internally
My task is to shrink the size of LRUCache for which I have written below code.
protected void shrinkSize() {
    Iterator iter = fetch iterator
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        if (size() > maxSize)
            iter.remove();
        else
            break;
    }
}

Here at iter.remove() I am facing ConcurrentModificationException as get calls to cache are happening parallely which changes the LRUcache structure.
is there a way to resolve the issue?

Your problem is that you need to synchronize externally.  LinkedHashMap is not a concurrent class.

synchronize at ?

You would synchronize on an object before you get the iterator, all of the other calls that can modify the LinkedHashMap also need to synchronize on the same object.

If you're doing this professionally, rather than for learning, then you should use a well-tested, industry-strength open-source library such as Caffeine.

Is it possible to inject Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap()); instead of a LinkedHashMap in your object ?

First of all, if you have one thread performing a put on a LinkedHashMap and another thread performing a get on the same map ... either at the same time OR at non-overlapping times ... then you have a thread-safety problem.  LinkedHashMap is not a concurrent class, and cannot be used in this scenario without proper external synchronization.
In a sense, the ConcurrentModificationExceptions that you are getting in shrinkSize() are a good thing.  They have surfaced the underlying thread-safety problem that you apparently weren't aware of.
So what is the solution?
Using a concurrent map is NOT the solution because there is no ConcurrentLinkedHashMap class.  (There is a ConcurrentHashMap, but that won't allow you to implement LRU removal.)
Instead, we need to use the non-concurrent, non-thread-safe LinkedHashMap class and synchronize the operations.  Here's one way to do it
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

/**
 * A simple thread-safe LRU cache class.
 */
public class LRUCache<K, V> {

    private static class MyCache<KK, VV> extends LinkedHashMap<KK, VV> {
        private final int maxSize;

        private MyCache(int maxSize) {
            super(maxSize, 0.75f, true);
            this.maxSize = maxSize;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<KK, VV> eldest) {
            return size() > this.maxSize;
        }
    }

    private final MyCache<K, V> myCache;  // don't leak this

    public LRUCache(int maxSize) {
       myCache = MyCache(maxSize);
    }

    public synchronized V get(K key) {
        return myCache.get(k);
    }

    public synchronized V put(K key, V value) {
        return myCache.put(k, v);
    }

    // Implement any other operations the cache needs to support.
    // They will need to synchronize on 'this'
}

Notes:

The removeEldestEntry method is called on updates to the linked hashmap. It decides whether or not to remove an entry.  The removal is done by the LinkedHashMap code.  Refer to the javadocs for more information.

The LRUCache class doesn't conform to the Map API.  If that was a requirement, you could have LRUCache extend LinkedHashMap directly, and then override all of the Map etc API methods to synchronize.  But (correctly) synchronizing the operations that return iterators or views would be tricky.



Individual calls are synchronised here, but one thread performing get and another thread performing remove can still result in ConcurrentModificationException. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

You are wrong.  1) Both a get and put operation will synchronize on this.  If they are called by different threads then a call on one thread will wait for the previous call on a different thread to finish.  The synchronized mechanism provides mutual exclusion.  2) Overriding removeEldestEntry doesn't entail an iteration that could result in a CCME.

Just synchronized will not work, have tested it with Collections.syncrhonized and it throws exception. Only ConcurentHashMap works, it removes items in a different way.

@MirceaSirghi - I'm not sure what you are saying, but when you remove using a removeEldestEntry method, that doesn't involve any iteration, so no CCME.  Note that we are NOT using Collections.synchronized here.  Indeed, LRUCache doesn't implement Map ... as written.

Was just going to test your class, when I realized that removeEldestEntry does not remove anything it just returns a Boolean. How are you actually using it, please provide an example.

Read the javadocs for LinkedHashMap.  They explain how this method works.

Wow, have tested your solution with 10 threads. it works, this is best solution so far: https://github.com/hackus/ConcurentLRUCache/blob/main/src/test/java/com/creativecoders/MainTest.java

Or encapsulate the cache operation into a command object, and then use a thread pool and thread-safe ordered queue to process it. When the operation task is stored in the queue, the acquisition task is triggered. The thread ends after acquiring all the tasks in the queue.Here is an example from my work, but this only works for monolithic services
/**
 * The number of threads in the thread pool is fixed at 1, and rejected tasks are discarded to ensure that there is only 1 operation at the same time.
 * The number of task queues is 2, which is used as a compensation trigger for fetching tasks to prevent new update operations from being added when the first task is deemed empty and exits.
 * Prevent caches from being overwritten by concurrent operations
 */
private final ExecutorService pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        1, 1, 0L,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(2),
        new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy()
);

/**
 * Store update operations and control the order of update operations
 */
private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DeptUserTreeService.QueueTask> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

/**
 * Queue the update task
 */
public void putEdit(DeptUserTreeService.EditDto dto, EditEnum edit) {
    if (dto == null || edit == null) return;
    putEdit(List.of(dto), edit);
}

/**
 * Queue the update task
 */
public void putEdit(List<DeptUserTreeService.EditDto> dtos, EditEnum edit) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(dtos) || edit == null) return;
    queue.add(new DeptUserTreeService.QueueTask(dtos, edit));
    pool.execute(this::queuePoll);
}

/**
 * Get and execute queue tasks
 */
private void queuePoll() {
    while (true) {
        DeptUserTreeService.QueueTask task = queue.poll();
        if (task == null) return;
        try {
            log.info("updateCacheBegin：{} -> {}", task.editEnum.name(), JSONUtil.toJsonStr(task.editDtoList));
            edit(task.editDtoList, task.editEnum);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("updateCacheError", e);
        }
    }
}

private void edit(List<DeptUserTreeService.EditDto> dtos, EditEnum edit) {

}


You can try use ConcurrentHashMap.Or create a public resource, and all cache operations need to compete for resources before they can be performed.

Nah.  It needs a >linked< hashmap, and there is no concurrent version.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300115/

Then you can try the following solution, create a public exclusive lock, all operations on the cache need to obtain the lock before proceeding, and release the lock after the operation is completed. If the lock is not obtained, you can retry to obtain the lock every x seconds until the upper limit of the number of retries is set.

That is over-engineered.  There is no need to do stuff with timeouts / retries unless the problem spec requires this.  The OP hasn't said anything about any of that.

This is a comment and should be removed, then you'll just have your answer remaining.
